# Node.JS Dynamo DB Vogels KeyCondition Error

Tags: node.js, database, amazon-web-services, vogels

I have been working with DynamoDB and the Vogels ORM library. For some reason, I have been receiving an error that I am unable to fix.

```
var BlogPost = vogels.define('BlogPost', {
  hashKey : 'email',
  rangeKey : ‘title’,
  schema : {
    email   : Joi.string().email(),
    title   : Joi.string(),
    content : Joi.binary(),
    tags   : vogels.types.stringSet(),
  }
});

BlogPost
.query('werner@example.com')
.exec(callback);
```

This code throws:

> { [ValidationException: Either the KeyConditions or
>   KeyConditionExpression parameter must be specified in the request.]
>   message: 'Either the KeyConditions or KeyConditionExpression parameter
>   must be specified in the request.',   code: 'ValidationException',
>   time: Sat Mar 19 2016 10:46:51 GMT-0400 (EDT),   requestId:
>   'A0YEPYICHOMPWNNUHY5AXR9BRYGIUMJO4P4ZDVUCHCKJNO9GDTXT',   statusCode:
>   400,   retryable: false,   retryDelay: 0 }

Is there something I am doing wrong? I can't seem to figure out this issue. Any help is greatly appreciated.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vogels 
https://github.com/ryanfitz/vogels

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the problem. I was using Dynalite for my testing environment and it was not handling the calls properly.